# Liquibase generating different UUIDs although uuid() called once inside <property>

Tags: mysql, uuid, liquibase

We ran the following in Liquibase:

```
<property name="UUID-20-off-General-US" value="uuid()" dbms="mysql"/>
<changeSet id="GeneralDiscountRateCard20" author="foo">
    <sql dbms="mysql">
        INSERT INTO rate (id, pricing_model, name)
        VALUES (${UUID-20-off-General-US}, 'CPM', '20% off Discount US');
        INSERT INTO rate_map (id, rate_map_name, rate_id)
        VALUES (uuid(), 'general_20_discount_us', ${UUID-20-off-General-US})
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

We expected to see the same UUID used in both tables (and a different UUID for the `id` of the second table). Instead, we found 3 different UUIDs. They looked almost identical, only differing in digits 5-8:

```
0dec159a-ded8-11e8-813e-42010a80044f
0dec7a69-ded8-11e8-813e-42010a80044f
0decc891-ded8-11e8-813e-42010a80044f
    ^^^^
```

Presumably because `uuid()` was called around the same fractional second.

Does `<property>` have delayed interpolation? Is there a way to actually have the same UUIDs between two references to `<property>`?

Comment: Your sql code only have two `INSERT INTO` commands, but you have 3 UUIDs. Where did the third row come from? And which tables are these UUIDs from? How do you run this code?

Comment: @Progman - This is Liquibase... just look up <property>.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `uuid()` will return different UUIDs by design, even when used in the same query.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT uuid(), uuid();
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| uuid()                               | uuid()                               |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| c6996867-e19c-11e8-b32e-e0cb4eeb0025 | c699686c-e19c-11e8-b32e-e0cb4eeb0025 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

When you ran your queries you will get the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO rate (id, pricing_model, name)
VALUES (uuid(), 'CPM', '20% off Discount US');
INSERT INTO rate_map (id, rate_map_name, rate_id)
VALUES (uuid(), 'general_20_discount_us', uuid())
```

resulting in three different UUIDs. When you want to "reuse" a value you have to save the value, not the function call, inside a variable/property and use it instead, something like this:

```
<property name="UUID-20-off-General-US" value="'c699686c-e19c-11e8-b32e-e0cb4eeb0025'" dbms="mysql"/>
<changeSet id="GeneralDiscountRateCard20" author="foo">
    <sql dbms="mysql">
        INSERT INTO rate (id, pricing_model, name)
        VALUES (${UUID-20-off-General-US}, 'CPM', '20% off Discount US');
        INSERT INTO rate_map (id, rate_map_name, rate_id)
        VALUES (uuid(), 'general_20_discount_us', ${UUID-20-off-General-US})
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Or you don't use a hardcoded `<property />` tag and pass the calculated value via Ant or the command line.

Comment: I understand that `uuid()` is a generator function. I guess my question is how do I reuse a generated value in two places in Liquibase? Does this mean 100% positively there's _no way_ to have an immediately computed value used as a property (or the same effect) in Liquibase?

Comment: @AndrewCheong You can calculate the value outside of the `<property>` tag via Ant or the command line with the value you want and use the variable substitution to use its value in the SQL query.

Comment: I understand there are ways to do this through the build chain. But I'm asking about Liquibase. Either (a) Yes, here's how ___, or (b) No, there's definitely no way to do this.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Another way is to use variables on the mysql side. You can use `SET @id = uuid();` and then use `@id` in your INSERT statements.